# Why printing images pixel values from a vector returns nonsense?

Tags: c++, image, matrix, vector

I have some code that looks at a directory of white and black images, reads it, resizes it and then pushes into a vector of images. However, when I call the images from the vector, it does not work. It prints out as if both images were white. What am I doing wrong here? Is it vector related?

```
vector<cv::Mat> images;
vector<cv::String> imageNames;

void prepareData(cv::String &directory)
{
    cv::glob(directory, imageNames, false);
    cv::Mat colorful, grey, out;
    number = imageNames.size();

    cout << "Number of images to train on " << number << endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        colorful = cv::imread(imageNames[i]);
        cv::resize(colorful, out, cv::Size(5, 5));
        cv::cvtColor(out, grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        images.push_back(grey);
        cout << grey << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
    {
        cout << "IMAGE " << i << " " << images[i] << endl;
    }
```

Here is the output I get. The 2 images at first show proper pixel values of the image (23 -> black, 255 -> white), but the second I recall it from the vector, I get that both of my images are white. What am I doing wrong?

```
Number of images to train on 2

[23, 23, 23, 23, 23;
  23, 23, 23, 23, 23;
  23, 23, 23, 23, 23;
  23, 23, 23, 23, 23;
  23, 23, 23, 23, 23]
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  254, 254, 255, 255, 255;
  254, 255, 255, 255, 254;
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255]


IMAGE 0 [255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  254, 254, 255, 255, 255;
  254, 255, 255, 255, 254;
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
IMAGE 1 [255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255;
  254, 254, 255, 255, 255;
  254, 255, 255, 255, 254;
  255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

Comment: In vector you have two `cv::Mat` instances which refers to `grey`, `cv::Mat` uses reference counter while copying. `images.push_back(grey);` - this doesn't copy data of `grey`, it just increases ref counter which refers to `grey`. So your output is correct, it shows content of `grey` mat.  You can create `grey` as local matrix inside *for* loop, then two different matrices will be stored inside vector.

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy operation of `cv::Mat` doesn't copy underlying data. `cv::Mat` uses reference counter mechanism. When copy is done, ref counter of copied matrix is increased, no data is copied.

Consider the code below:

```
vector<cv::Mat> vec;
cv::Mat m1;
vec.push_back(m1); // vec[0] refers to m1
some operations on m1
```

now the printed content of `vec[0]` and `m1` will be the same.

In *for* loop you are pushing two new instances of `cv::Mat` but they refer to `grey` data. So when you are printing contents of vector, you see **the last modification** on `grey` matrix.

Create `out` and `grey` as local inside *for* loop:

```
    colorful = cv::imread(imageNames[i]);
    cv::Mat out, grey; // <----- added
    cv::resize(colorful, out, cv::Size(5, 5));
    cv::cvtColor(out, grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    images.push_back(grey);
    cout << grey << endl;
```

Another solution is to use [clone](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#afb01ff6b2231b72f55618bfb66a5326b) method that makes deep copy of `cv::Mat`.